# Problems with firing query on a database table in phpMyAdmin. Obtaining 0 rows as result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using `phpMyAdmin` for feeding data and I ran into a problem. I am not much experienced with normalisation of data. But I am trying a few stuff out.

I have some tables in my database as shown below:

```
-- Table name `Universities`
SrNo  ||  University
-----     ----------
 1         Harvard
 2         Boston
 3         Oxford
 4         Stanford 
 5         Dublin
```

I created the above table as:

```
CREATE TABLE Universities (

    SrNo INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    University LONGTEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Now I have another table as:

```
--Table name `Courses`
SrNo  ||  Course
----      ------
  1       Maths
  2       Physics
  3       Computer Science
  4       Electronics
  5       Chemistry
```

I created the above table as:

```
CREATE TABLE Courses (

    SrNo INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Course LONGTEXT
);
```

Now the problem is that one university offers `n` number of courses where `n` may or may not be equal for each university. And each course is offered by `m` number of universities where `m` may or may not be equal for each subject.

For example:

```
Harvard --> Maths, Electronics, Physics                 (3 subjects)
Boston  --> Maths, Computer Science                     (2 subjects)
Stanford -> Chemistry, Electronics, Computer Science    (3 subjects)
Oxford  --> Physics, Chemistry, Maths, Computer Science (4 subjects)
Dublin  -->                                             (0 subjects)
```

As there is no way of firing a JOIN query(as per my knowledge LIMIT) to extract the name of university along with the courses they offer, so as per my teachers advice (or maybe a hint), what I did is I created another table which will store references of `Universities.SrNo` and `Courses.SrNo`.

```
SrNo  ||  UnivID  ||  CourseID
----      ------      --------
  1          1            1    -- This means Harvard(SrNo=1 in table `Universities`) offers Maths(SrNo=1 in table `Courses`)
  1          1            4
  1          1            2
  1          2            1
  1          2            3
  1          4            5
  1          4            4
  1          4            3
  1          3            2
  1          3            4
  1          3            1
  1          3            3
  1          5          null
```

I created the above table as:

```
CREATE TABLE Reference (

    SrNo INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UnivID INT NOT NULL,
    CourseID INT,      -- m not giving this a not null constraint coz a university may offer none of the course mentioned in the table `Courses`
);
```

With the help of this, I am trying to extract the University name and the Courses name they offer.

Like if I want to list all courses offered by `Harvard`, this is what I do:

```
SELECT Universities.University, Courses.Course FROM Universities, Courses, Reference
WHERE Universities.University="Harvard" AND Reference.UnivID = Universities.SrNo
```

But I get 0 rows as a result.

What should I do?
**1>** Is there any way to get this result without the table named `Reference`:

```
Harvard    Maths
Harvard    Electronics
Harvard    Physics
```

**2>** If yes, then how? If no, the how should I build my SQL query to get the above mentioned result in **1**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by  nested query :

```
Select U.University,C.Course from Universities U, Course C where C.SrNo in (
Select R.CourseID from Reference R where UnivId in (select U1.SrNo from Universities U1 where U1.University ="Stanford" ))
```

Comment: Is there no simple way of doing it? Can you please explain how this works?

Comment: @Aditya You first try subdivide the question and basis of that structure the nested queries.      In this case `select U1.SrNo from Universities U1 where U1.University ="Stanford"` will fetch the ID of university Stanford now on the basis of this ID you can fetch courseID from Reference Table and ultimately will achieve University Course pairs. **Always to read nested queries inner part first and correlate it with outer query this will definitely help you to read as well as understand nested queries**

Comment: Ok. One last question. What does the `in` clause do? What is is used for?

Comment: @Aditya In SQL "in" clause used to check whether the columns value contains any among the following set of value i.e For example : you want a name of a persons who are having ages (21 22 23 24 ...) so you will write your SQL something like ' select name from Employee where age in (21,22,23,.....)'  . For more clarification :  General Syntax is 'SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...);' refer http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp url.